# structured bindings: when something looks like a reference and behaves similarly to a reference, but it's not a reference

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, structured-bindings

Yesterday I've seen [an interesting question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44671697/what-are-the-types-of-identifiers-introduced-by-structured-bindings-in-c17/44672220#44672220) here on SO about structured binding.
We can sum up it as it follows. Consider the example code below:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

int main() {
    auto tup = std::make_tuple(1, 2);
    auto & [ a, b ] = tup;
    // the following line won't compile for a isn't a reference
    // static_assert(std::is_reference_v<decltype(a)>);
}
```

In this case `decltype(a)` is `int` (probably) because of [this bullet](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.simple#4.1) (working draft):

> if `e` is an unparenthesized id-expression naming a structured binding [...], `decltype(e)` is the referenced type as given in the specification of the structured binding declaration

[Here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/BKLeZRzPubEsPC5l) is a snippet on wandbox provided by @Curious in the comments for those that are interested. It shows that actually `a` isn't a reference, nothing more.
So far so good for the original question, OP asked why it was `int` instead of `int &` and *the standard says that* looked like an acceptable answer.

Anyway, I'd like to know why the committee decided so. At the end of the day, `a` refers to an element in the tuple and I can modify that element through `a`. In other terms, the declaration of `a` looks like the one of a reference, it behaves similarly to a reference but it's not a reference.

I can live with this, but I'd like to know what are the reasons behind that. Why `decltype(a)` cannot be simply `int &`? Is there a meaningful reason that a profane can understand?

Comment: Can you extend your example to actually demonstrate that `a` is not a reference?  It should be fairly easy to `static_assert` something like `std::is_reference<decltype(a)>::value`.

Comment: @TobySpeight In the original question there is the example you are asking for. That being said, you can simply print out `std::is_reference_v<decltype(a)>` and it will return 0, as well as `std:.is_same_v<decltype(a), int &>`, while `std:.is_same_v<decltype(a), int>`will return 1. That's quite simple.

Comment: @TobySpeight use an online compiler https://wandbox.org/permlink/BKLeZRzPubEsPC5l?

Comment: I absolutely hate how `a` and `b` are not references here

Comment: @Curious I agree and that's why I'm interested in the actual reasons, if any.

Comment: In [section 11.5.3](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.struct.bind#3), there's text saying "*Given the type `Ti` designated by `std​::​tuple_­element<i, E>​::​type`, each `vi` is a variable of type “reference to `Ti`” initialized with the initializer, where the reference is an *lvalue reference* if the initializer is an *lvalue* and an *rvalue* reference otherwise; the referenced type is `Ti`.*"  That seems to me to suggest that `auto & [  ]` ought to declare references...

Comment: @TobySpeight Unfortunately it doesn't. I see your point, but it doesn't conform with the bullet that rules on `decltype`. That's why it's confusing me actually.

Comment: @Curious I hate how `decltype(a)` has a special case that makes `int a; int &b = a;` distinguishable from `int b; int &a = b;` - it breaks a nice symmetry (and I see this flaw as leading to the problem in this question)

Comment: In other words , `a` is an lvalue that designates an `int`; the question is what information do you hope to obtain by `decltype(a)` ? How will you use the result?

Comment: @M.M And what would you expect [this result](https://wandbox.org/permlink/7gGd8O80F3hWx0Lx) to be when you're told `decltype(a)` is not a reference?

Comment: @O'Neil well that's what this question is about

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[I wrote this yesterday](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding):

> `decltype(x)`, where `x` is a structured binding, names the referenced
>   type of that structured binding. In the tuple-like case, this is the
>   type returned by `std::tuple_element`, which may not be a reference
>   even though the structured binding itself is in fact always a
>   reference in this case. This effectively emulates the behavior of
>   binding to a struct whose non-static data members have the types
>   returned by `tuple_element`, with the referenceness of the binding
>   itself being a mere implementation detail.

Comment: Damnit, I've read that page yesterday, probably before the edit.

Comment: So, to put it in simple words, it's like `some_struct.member`?

Comment: So, `auto[a,b] = exp` and `auto&[a,b] = exp` have very different behavior (for many cases of exp), yet `decltype(a)` in both cases is identical?

Comment: @Yakk seems like it, DanielJour and T.C.'s analogy explains this pretty nicely, I think I understand this now

Comment: @T.C. if you wrote that could you maybe try and move that explanation somewhere near the top of the page?  Because this makes what structured bindings actually do a lot clearer (to me at least, I suspect to others as well) and a lot of what is on that page there is hard to understand (for mortals like me)

Comment: So `decltype` returns a referenced type meaning if it returns `int`, it actually implied `int&`?

Answer (score -1):

This topic has been covered before (look in the structured-bindings tag) and the behavior you're talking about is even addressed in the second answer. However, the rationale is spelled out in [p0144r2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0144r2.pdf) section 3.5:

> Should the syntax be extended to allow `const/&`-qualifying individual
>   names' types?
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> auto [&x, const y, const& z] = f(); // NOT proposed
> ```
>
> We think the answer should be no. This is a simple feature to store a
>   value and bind names to its components,  not to declare multiple
>   variables. Allowing such qualification would be feature creep,
>   extending the feature to be something different, namely a way to
>   declare multiple variables.
>
> If we do want to declare multiple variables, we already have a way to
>   spell it:
>
> ```
>  auto val    = f();
>  T& x        = get<0>(val);
>  T2 const y  = get<1>(val);
>  T3 const& z = get<2>(val);
> ```

Comment: I don't think this is relevant: the question is why the reference qualifier on the structured binding as a whole does not apply to both declared elements thereof - not why those elements can't be individually qualified.