# Is decltype(auto) for a structured binding supposed to be a reference?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, structured-bindings

Consider an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>

int main() {
    auto tup = std::make_tuple(1, 2);
    auto [ a, b ] = tup;
    decltype(auto) e = a;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_reference_v<decltype(e)> << std::endl;
}
```

[clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/1dKQfkLgiXHNkBno) (output: `false`) and [gcc](https://wandbox.org/permlink/1dKQfkLgiXHNkBno) (output: `true`) are disagreeing in this simple case. Having in mind e.g. [this Q&As](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44695684/4324224) should the `e` be a reference or is it a gcc bug? Or maybe the code is ill-formed?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The identifers *themselves* are references. From [[dcl.struct.bind]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.struct.bind#3):

> Given the type T<sub>i</sub> designated by `std​::​tuple_­element<i, E>​::​type`, each v<sub>i</sub> is a variable of type “reference to T<sub>i</sub>” initialized with the initializer, where the reference is an lvalue reference if the initializer is an lvalue and an rvalue reference otherwise; the referenced type is T<sub>i</sub>.

That is, `a` and `b` are both `int&&`.

But the way `decltype(auto)` actually behaves comes from [[dcl.type.auto.deduct]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.spec.auto#dcl.type.auto.deduct-5):

> If the placeholder is the `decltype(auto)` type-specifier, `T` shall be the placeholder alone. The type deduced for `T` is determined as described in [dcl.type.simple], as though `e` had been the operand of the `decltype`.

This wording is really awkward, but ultimately:

```
decltype(auto) e = a;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

means:

```
decltype( a  ) e = a;
         ~~~~
```

and `decltype(a)` means, from [[dcl.type.simple]/4.1](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.simple#4.1):

> if `e` is an unparenthesized *id-expression* naming a structured binding ([dcl.struct.bind]), `decltype(e)` is **the referenced type** as given in the specification of the structured binding declaration;

The *referenced type* of `a` is `int`, so `e` must be an `int`. Which means it's not a reference, and clang is correct. Filed [81176](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=81176).