# why structured bindings don't return references to struct members using `auto&` but the members themselves are returned

Tags: c++, c++17, structured-bindings

I thought that using structured bindings and `auto&` specifier I can obtain references to structure members and use them directly instead of going through the structure.

However, the following code works and the static asserts hold:

```
struct Test
{
    int i;
    char c;
    double d;
};
Test test{ 0, 1, 2 };
auto& [i, c, d] = test;
i = 4;
c = 5;
d = 6;
// i, c, d are not references !
static_assert(!std::is_same_v<decltype(i), int&>);
static_assert(!std::is_same_v<decltype(c), char&>);
static_assert(!std::is_same_v<decltype(d), double&>);
cout << &i << " == " << &test.i << " (" << std::boolalpha << (&i == &test.i) << ")" << endl; // (true)
cout << test.i << ", " << (int)test.c << ", " << test.d << endl; // 4, 5, 6
```

But I thought C++ doesn't allow one variable to have more than one name except if one is the real variable and others are references but in this case the variable `i` is the same as `test.i` and neither of them is a reference.

Comment: `i` *is* a reference in the code you show. `auto& [i ...` - That's a reference.

Comment: It does allow it if the two variables are i different scopes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the array and type case, structured bindings aren't references - they're aliases to the corresponding members. The main reason for this is to support bitfields. You can't have a reference to a bitfield, but you can have an alias to one:

```
struct X {
    uint8_t a : 2;
    uint8_t b : 6;
};

void f(X& x) {
    auto& [a, b] = x; // fine, a just means "x.a"
    auto& a2 = x.a;   // error
}
```

Separately from that, `decltype()` does something [special](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44698195/2069064) on structured bindings - it will only ever give you a reference type if the member the binding refers to is a reference type, as in:

```
struct Y {
    int& a;
    int b;
};

void f(Y& y) {
    auto& [a, b] = y;
    // decltype(a) is int&, decltype(b) is int
}
```

Comment: Do you know, btw, how to force "constness" of structured binding's identifier so it WON'T BE ABLE to modify lvalue of such underlying *non-const* reference? `const auto & [a]` obviously does not pertain to the identifier - `const` is ignored in such case (as no const reference is possible). Is it possible on "structured binding level" in C++?