# `ref-qualified` `identifier-list` is not a reference in C++ Structured binding but act as one

Tags: c++, c++20, structured-bindings

In C++ [Structured binding](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) if we use `&` as the `ref-qualifier` like bellow:

```
tuple tpl{ 1 };
auto& [myInt] = tpl;
```

when we assign to `myInt`, changes are reflected to `tpl`:

```
myInt = -1;
cout << get<0>(tpl) << "    " << endl; // -1
```

Here `myInt` ac as a reference. But when we query the type of `myInt` we get `int`, not `int&`!

```
cout << type_name<decltype(myInt)>() << endl;
```

How is that possible?!

This [article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20201014-00/?p=104367) goes deeper into the Structured binding and states:

> In a cruel twist of fate, if hidden is const or a const reference, then that const-ness propagates to the destinations. But the reference-ness of hidden does not propagate.

How reference-ness does not propagate but still act as one?

Here is the complete code and the result compiled with MS Visual Studio 2022 with the latest C++ standard.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

template <typename T>
constexpr auto type_name() {
    std::string_view name, prefix, suffix;
#ifdef __clang__
    name = __PRETTY_FUNCTION__;
    prefix = "auto type_name() [T = ";
    suffix = "]";
#elif defined(__GNUC__)
    name = __PRETTY_FUNCTION__;
    prefix = "constexpr auto type_name() [with T = ";
    suffix = "]";
#elif defined(_MSC_VER)
    name = __FUNCSIG__;
    prefix = "auto __cdecl type_name<";
    suffix = ">(void)";
#endif
    name.remove_prefix(prefix.size());
    name.remove_suffix(suffix.size());
    return name;
}

using namespace std;

int main() {
    tuple tpl{ 1 };

    decltype(auto) myIntRef{ get<0>(tpl) };
    cout << type_name<decltype(myIntRef)>() << endl;
    
    auto& [myInt] = tpl;
    myInt = -1;
    cout << type_name<decltype(myInt)>() << endl;
    cout << get<0>(tpl) << "    " << endl;
}
```

and the result:

```
int&
int
-1
```

Comment: please add the missing includes

Comment: No `include`s should be missing now.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44698195/817643