# Does copy elision work with structured bindings

Tags: c++, c++17, rvalue, copy-elision, structured-bindings

Does mandatory copy elision apply to decomposition via structured bindings?  Which of the following cases does that apply to?

```
// one
auto [one, two] = std::array<SomeClass>{SomeClass{1}, SomeClass{2}};

// two
auto [one, two] = std::make_tuple(SomeClass{1}, SomeClass{2});

// three
struct Something { SomeClass one, two; };
auto [one, two] = Something{};
```

I suspect only the third case allows for copy elision, since the first two will be "decomposed" via `std::get<>` and `std::tuple_size<>` and `std::get<>` returns xvalues when the arguments are rvalues

A quote from the standard would be nice also!

Comment: Yes, and it's easy to see why when you consider what structured bindings actually desugar to. ;-]

Comment: @ildjarn by yes are you confirming that `one` and `two` will not result in copy elision but `three` will?

Comment: I mean 'yes, copy elision works with structured bindings' – `one` and `three` will result in guaranteed copy elision, `two` won't.

Comment: but those binding  aren't in standard? and array needs extra argument

Comment: @ildjarn But one only allows access via `get<>` and `tuple_size` function/method/traits?  From what it seemed like the thing on the right hand side (from what I could make out by reading the standard) has to be either an array or a class that has all public members, can structured bindings be recursive in this way?

Comment: @Curious : Again, it's important to understand what structured bindings actually desugar to. `get<>` and `tuple_size` are irrelevant.

Comment: @ildjarn the way I understand it, first the decomposition is going to try and decompose the instance on the right manually without using (ADL defined or member) `get<>` or `tuple_size` and if that does not work. the implementation will fall back to using those.  And in the case of `std::array` I'm not sure if the decomposition falls back recursively to the contained array member.  Despite the thing being an aggregate (aggregates were not mentioned in the standard spec for structured bindings if I recall correctly)

Comment: @ildjarn what did I get wrong in my understanding above?

Comment: @Curious : You left out the "*[uniquely-named variable to hold the value of the initializer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding)*".

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> Does mandatory copy elision apply to decomposition via structured bindings? Which of the following cases does that apply to?

Yes, all of them. The point of structured bindings is to give you named references to the destructured elements of the type you're binding to. This:

```
auto [one, two] = expr;
```

Is just syntax sugar for:

```
auto __tmp = expr;
some_type<0,E>& one = some_getter<0>(__tmp);
some_type<1,E>& two = some_getter<1>(__tmp);
```

Where `some_type` and `some_getter` depend on the kind of type we're destructuring (array, tuple-like, or type with all public non-static data members).

Mandatory copy elision applies in the `auto __tmp = expr` line, none of the other lines involve copies.

---

There's some confusion around an example in the comments, so let me elaborate on what happens in:

```
auto [one, two] = std::make_tuple(Something{}, Something{});
```

That [expands into](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.struct.bind#1.sentence-8):

```
auto __tmp = std::make_tuple(Something{}, Something{}); // note that it is from
// std::make_tuple() itself that we get the two default constructor calls as well
// as the two copies.
using __E = std::remove_reference_t<decltype(__tmp)>; // std::tuple<Something, Something>
```

Then, since `__E` is [not an array type](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.struct.bind#2.sentence-1) but [is tuple-like](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.struct.bind#3.sentence-1), we introduce variables via an [unqualified call to `get` looked up in the associated namespace of `__E`](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.struct.bind#3.sentence-3). The initializer will be an [xvalue](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.struct.bind#3.sentence-5) and the types will be [rvalue references](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.struct.bind#3.sentence-6):

```
std::tuple_element_t<0, __E>&& one = get<0>(std::move(__tmp));
std::tuple_element_t<1, __E>&& two = get<1>(std::move(__tmp));
```

Note that while `one` and `two` are both rvalue references into `__tmp`, `decltype(one)` and `decltype(two)` will [both yield `Something`](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.simple#4.1) and not `Something&&`.

Comment: https://wandbox.org/permlink/1pRlbWw06mVDguPN This is not how I have understood this. The way I understand it, structured bindings create an anonymous class/struct with the types of the variables being the same as those of the RHS (if `tuple_element` exists then that will be used to determine type) and then the regular decomposition process follows for that struct

Comment: @Curious: Structured binding does nothing of the kind. It does not create classes at all.

Comment: @NicolBolas I know it doesn't, that's just my mental model.  And it has worked so far...

Comment: Nitpick: names with double underscores (`__tmp`) are reserved - don't use such names in examples.

Comment: @Curious `make_tuple` (and `tuple` in general) requires materializing temporaries to bind to the reference parameters of `make_tuple` (or `tuple`'s constructor) when you create a tuple. That has nothing to do with structured bindings.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I use names with double underscores in examples to illustrate names that are introduced by the language, much the same way the standard uses `__range`, `__begin`, and `__end` to define the meaning of a range-based for statement.

Comment: @JesperJuhl It's intended to illustrate how the compiler desugars a structured binding declaration. And the compiler had better use reserved names for the variables it introduces!

Comment: @T.C. ah that makes sense. yes.  I forgot to consider how the tuple constructor requires moving since it accepts forwarding references

Comment: @Barry could you mention how the `decltype` of `a` and `b` will not be what your syntactic sugar expansion has produced?  They will not be references, but in your example they will.  I will accept the answer then!

Comment: @T.C. My mental model was referring to your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/44696826/5501675

Comment: @Curious Doesn't the link to T.C.'s answer you just posted ^^ answer your question?

Comment: @Barry I don't think so, where does it mention how temporaries fit in here?

Comment: @Curious You're asking what `decltype(a)` means when `a` comes from a structured bindings. That is the topic of the linked question.

Comment: @Barry I understand that, I meant the question I have asked above (the main question i.e.) about copy elision, not the one asking you to include that the syntax sugar above does not translate well to the `decltype` of the variables in the structured binding declaration

Comment: @Curious That's the first sentence of the answer: "Yes, all of them"

Comment: @Barry Sorry I am not being clear.  What I mean is, with your answer above it might make someone seem like the variables introduced by the structured bindings are of reference type (because you introduced them in the expansion with `auto&`),  could you just mention that they are not references (may be, based on the types of the thing on the RHS) in your answer?

Comment: @Curious They *are* references.

Comment: @Barry but if you take a look at the cppreference documentation it says "In these initializer expressions, e is an lvalue if the type of the entity e is an lvalue reference (this only happens if the ref-operator is & or if it is && and the initializer expression is an lvalue) and an xvalue otherwise (this effectively performs a kind of perfect forwarding)"  Meaning that the hidden variable is better described as being a forwarding reference?

Comment: @Curious : `e` is a _variable_, formally; references are not variables. The part you're quoting regards the expression _e_ and its value category in subsequent text. I mean you are conflating value category with storage; "*a structured binding declaration first introduces a uniquely-named variable*" is not ambiguous, and means a new _object_, not reference. If that doesn't sufficiently explain things then you need to ask a different question, TBH, or at least read the pages that have been linked here already.

Comment: @ildjarn Doesn't `type of the entity e is an lvalue reference` imply that `decltype(e)` is an lvalue reference?

Comment: You said you read that answer of @T.C.'s that you linked to; your questions strongly indicate otherwise. ;-]

Comment: @ildjarn what did I miss??  The answer even says "even though the structured binding itself is in fact always a reference in this case", which does not say anything that would mean that the structured binding is not a reference type.

Comment: The structured binding is not its uniquely-named variable; the former _has_ the latter, but they are not the same semantically. The uniquely-named variable is _always an object_, because it is a 'variable' (in formal terms); the structured binding that sits atop that object represents itself differently (so as to _appear_ to have the same ref-qualifier as the user's binding declaration). But again, do not conflate the two.

Answer (score 4):

Interesting question:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <tuple>
#include <typeinfo>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

struct SomeClass
{
    int baz;

    SomeClass(int _b): baz(_b) {
        cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << " = " << baz << endl;
    }
    SomeClass(SomeClass&&) {
        cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl;
    }
    SomeClass(const SomeClass&) {
        cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl;
    }
};

template<typename T> void tell(T&& a)
{
    cout << "Tell: " << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << " = " << a.baz << endl;
}

int main()
{
     // one
     cout << "= 1 =" << endl;
     auto [one, two] = std::array<SomeClass,2>{SomeClass{1}, SomeClass{2}};
     cout << "===" << endl;
     tell(one); tell(two);
     // two
     cout << endl << "= 2 =" << endl;
     auto [one2, two2] = std::make_tuple(SomeClass{1}, SomeClass{2});
     cout << "===" << endl;
     tell(one2); tell(two2);
     // three
     cout << endl << "= 3 =" << endl;
     struct Something { SomeClass one{1}, two{2}; };     
     auto [one3, two3] = Something{}; 
     cout << "===" << endl;
     tell(one3); tell(two3);

    return 0;
}
```

Produces output:

```
= 1 =
SomeClass::SomeClass(int) = 1
SomeClass::SomeClass(int) = 2
===
Tell: void tell(T&&) [with T = SomeClass&] = 1
Tell: void tell(T&&) [with T = SomeClass&] = 2

= 2 =
SomeClass::SomeClass(int) = 2
SomeClass::SomeClass(int) = 1
SomeClass::SomeClass(SomeClass&&)
SomeClass::SomeClass(SomeClass&&)
===
Tell: void tell(T&&) [with T = SomeClass&] = 0
Tell: void tell(T&&) [with T = SomeClass&] = 4199261

= 3 =
SomeClass::SomeClass(int) = 1
SomeClass::SomeClass(int) = 2
===
Tell: void tell(T&&) [with T = SomeClass&] = 1
Tell: void tell(T&&) [with T = SomeClass&] = 2
```

Second case uses either copy or move (if available)   constructor.  Values weren't  initialized, because  I intentionally didn't do that in constructors.

There are three protocols of binding

- binding to array
- binding to tuple-like type
- binding to public data members

In second case (sorry, I don't have access to C++17 pdf, so cppreference):

> Each identifier becomes a variable whose type is "reference to
>   `std::tuple_element<i, E>::type`": lvalue reference if its corresponding
>   initializer is an lvalue, rvalue reference otherwise. The initializer
>   for the i-th identifier is
>
> - `e.get<i>()`, if lookup for the identifier get in the scope of E by class member access lookup finds at least one declaration (of whatever
>     kind)
> - Otherwise, `get<i>(e)`, where get is looked up by argument-dependent lookup only, ignoring non-ADL lookup

First and second stage of example are actually  bindings to tuple-like type.
But... In second stage what we use to initialize? A template function that constructs tuple:

```
 std::make_tuple(SomeClass{1}, SomeClass{2});
```

which would actually either copy or move values. Further copy elision may occur, but

```
 auto t = std::make_tuple(SomeClass{1}, SomeClass{2});
 auto [one2, two2] = t;
```

would produce this output:

```
SomeClass::SomeClass(int) = 2
SomeClass::SomeClass(int) = 1
SomeClass::SomeClass(SomeClass&&)      //make_tuple
SomeClass::SomeClass(SomeClass&&)
SomeClass::SomeClass(const SomeClass&) //assignment 
SomeClass::SomeClass(const SomeClass&)
```

Although properly de-sugaring structured binding looks like:

```
 auto t = std::make_tuple(SomeClass{1}, SomeClass{2});
 auto& one2 = std::get<0>(t);
 auto& two2 = std::get<1>(t);
```

and output  matches original:

```
SomeClass::SomeClass(int) = 2
SomeClass::SomeClass(int) = 1
SomeClass::SomeClass(SomeClass&&)
SomeClass::SomeClass(SomeClass&&)
===
```

So, the copy or move operation that happens, is  from constructing our `tuple`.
We would avoid that, if we construct tuple using universal references, then both desugared

```
 auto t = std::tuple<SomeClass&&, SomeClass&&>(SomeClass{1}, SomeClass{2});
 auto& one2 = std::get<0>(t);
 auto& two2 = std::get<1>(t);
```

and structured binding

```
 auto [one2, two2] = std::tuple<SomeClass&&, SomeClass&&>(SomeClass{1}, SomeClass{2});
```

would result in copy elision.