# Type of variables in structured binding

Tags: c++, c++17, auto, decltype, type-deduction

```
#include <type_traits>

int main()
{
    int arr[1] = { 6 };

    auto& ref1 = arr[0];  
    static_assert( std::is_same_v<decltype( ref1 ), int&> ); //ok

    auto& [ ref2 ] = arr;
    static_assert( std::is_same_v<decltype( ref2 ), int> ); //ok
    static_assert( std::is_same_v<decltype( ref2 ), int&> ); //error
}
```

What is the consequential difference between identifiers `ref1` and `ref2` in that example? As I understand, `ref2` in structure binding also has a reference type, but why does `decltype` indicate a non-referenced type for it?

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44695684/structured-bindings-when-something-looks-like-a-reference-and-behaves-similarly) answers your question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`decltype(e)` behaves differently depending on what `e` is given as the argument. For the structured binding, `decltype` yields what follows, [[dcl.type.simple]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.simple#4.1):

> For an expression `e`, the type denoted by `decltype(e)` is defined as follows:
>
> - if `e` is an unparenthesized *id-expression* naming a structured binding, `decltype(e)` is **the referenced type** as given in the specification of the structured binding declaration

The referenced type for a structured binding declaration with an array type expression as the initializer is the type of the element [[dcl.struct.bind]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.struct.bind#3):

> If `E` is an array type with element type `T`, the number of elements in the identifier-list shall be equal to the number of elements of `E`. Each *v<sub>i</sub>*  is the name of an lvalue that refers to the element *i* of the array and whose type is `T`; **the referenced type is `T`**. [ *Note*: The top-level cv-qualifiers of T are cv. — *end note* ]